# Missing 64-bit version of librealmreact.so

Tags: realm

Using:

```
realm 2.22.0
react-native 0.58.5
```

Attempting to run on Android (6.0) 64-bit Huawei P9 lite
Building with Android Studio

Application crashes immediately with error:

> E/SoLoader: Error when loading lib: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.netballninja/lib-main/librealmreact.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit lib .....

Running the application on 32-bit Android simulator is fine.

I have analyzed the APK file and indeed under `/libs/arm64-v8a` the librealmreact.so does not exist (only under armeabi-v7a). 64-bit support appears to have been back ported into react-native 0.58.4 (originally slated for 0.59).

I have tried removing the inclusion of `arm64-v8a` support from the APK, (thinking that Android OS would drop back to 32-bit if no 64-bit libs were present) and the application does then run in 32-bit mode on the 64-bit device.

I assume that I do require a librealmreact.so that is 64-bit (precompiled). How do I ensure that my bundling includes that?

Answer (score 1):

you must add this line to app/build.gradle

```
android {
    ....
    defaultConfig {
        ....
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug of [SoLoader](https://github.com/facebook/SoLoader).

Fixed in v0.8.0 by [this](https://github.com/facebook/SoLoader/pull/45).

As you said, the real reason which causes app crashed is that:

> the application does then run in 32-bit mode on the 64-bit device.

SoLoader will follow certain of rules to extract some .so files from .apk file when the application runs first time. In 64-bit device, if the .apk file includes 64-bit .so files, soloader will extract them instead of 32-bit files.

---

Therefore, you can try to fix this problem by following the steps below:

1. Make sure that `build.gradle` of module like this:

```
...
android {
...
    splits {
        abi {
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
       ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
       }
    }
}
```

2. If step1 can not fix your problem, try to upgrade SoLoader to version 0.8.0:

```
configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy {
       force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.0"
     }
}
```